Shift arrow tail
I have seen in the xypic guide that you can shift the tail by adding the command
\newdir{ >}{{}*!/-5pt/@{>}}.
However, this doesn't work if the arrow isn't to the right. Is there a way to make it so that the spacing is always in the direction of the arrow?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\newdir{ >}{{}*!/-5pt/@{>}}

\newcommand{\mfg}{\mathfrak{g}}
\newcommand{\mfh}{\mathfrak{h}}
\newcommand{\KK}{\mathbb{K}}
\newcommand{\ab}{\mathrm{ab}}
\newcommand{\lie}[2]{[#1,#2]}

\begin{document}

\xymatrix{
    & H_2(\mfg/\mfh,\KK) \ar[r]^f \ar[d]^\alpha & (\mfh\ab)_{\mfg/\mfh} \ar[r]^g & \mfg\ab \ar[r] & (\mfg/\mfh)\ab \ar[r] & 0 \\
    H_2(\mfg/\mfh,\KK)\oplus\lie{\mfg}{\mfh} \ar@{-->}[r] \ar@{->>}[ur] \ar@{->>}[dr]& \ker\varphi \ar@{ >->}[r] & \mfh\ab \ar@{->>}[u] \ar[ur]^\varphi \\
    & \lie{\mfg}{\mfh} \ar[u] \ar@{->>}[r] & \lie{\mfg}{\mfh}/\com{\mfh} \ar@{ >->}[u]
    }.
\end{document}

gives me

but if I remove the cmtip part and only write \usepackage[all]{xy}, I get that


I made a few experiments, but the arrow tip is always shifted as expected in various directions. Can you please show an example?

@egreg I editted the main post

The code is necessary.

I can't reproduce the issue.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\newcommand{\mfg}{\mathfrak{g}}
\newcommand{\mfh}{\mathfrak{h}}
\newcommand{\KK}{\mathbb{K}}
\newcommand{\ab}{^{\mathrm{ab}}}
\newcommand{\lie}[2]{[#1,#2]}
\newcommand{\com}[1]{\lie{#1}{#1}}

\newdir{ >}{{}*!/-5pt/@{>}}

\begin{document}

\xymatrix{
  &
  H_2(\mfg/\mfh,\KK) \ar[r]^f \ar[d]^\alpha &
  (\mfh\ab)_{\mfg/\mfh} \ar[r]^g &
  \mfg\ab \ar[r] &
  (\mfg/\mfh)\ab \ar[r] &
  0
  \\
  H_2(\mfg/\mfh,\KK)\oplus\lie{\mfg}{\mfh} \ar@{-->}[r] \ar@{->>}[ur] \ar@{->>}[dr] &
  \ker\varphi \ar@{ >->}[r] &
  \mfh\ab \ar@{->>}[u] \ar[ur]^\varphi
  \\
  &
  \lie{\mfg}{\mfh} \ar[u] \ar@{->>}[r] &
  \lie{\mfg}{\mfh}/\com{\mfh} \ar@{ >->}[u]
}

\end{document}


The output is definitely better if you add cmtip: no other change other than
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}


Now I'll show how to do it with tikz-cd, which results with even better output.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\mfg}{\mathfrak{g}}
\newcommand{\mfh}{\mathfrak{h}}
\newcommand{\KK}{\mathbb{K}}
\newcommand{\ab}{\mathrm{ab}}
\newcommand{\lie}[2]{[#1,#2]}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
&
H_2(\mfg/\mfh,\KK) \arrow[r,"f"] \arrow[d,"\alpha"] &
(\mfh^{\ab})_{\mfg/\mfh} \arrow[r,"g"] &
\mfg^{\ab} \arrow[r] &
(\mfg/\mfh)^{\ab} \arrow[r] &
0
\\
H_2(\mfg/\mfh,\KK)\oplus\lie{\mfg}{\mfh} \arrow[r,dashed] \arrow[ur,->>] \arrow[dr,->>] &
\ker\varphi \arrow[r,>->] &
\mfh^{\ab} \arrow[u,->>] \arrow[ur,"\varphi"']
\\
&
\lie{\mfg}{\mfh} \arrow[u] \arrow[r,->>] &
\lie{\mfg}{\mfh}/\lie{\mfh}{\mfh} \arrow[u,>->]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}



I've added it. Your code isn't what I want tho, the arrow should look like >-> on the bottom right

@Jolia I can't reproduce the issue, see the updated answer

That's weird cause I can't solve it with what you suggested, I'd rather use xypic than tikz. I don't really know how to use tikz so...

@Jolia Please, add a short, but complete, example, from \documentclass to \end{document} that shows the issue.

I've editted the poslt, hope it's better now

@Jolia No issue for me. The arrow is as expected.

That is really weird, I'll investigate
